# How to set values for Needleman-Wunsch algorithm so raster shifts are not penalised?

Tags: sequence-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I recently found out, that the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm (NW) comes very close to what I need to match my patterns. In particular, I have 2 sequences (toy example):

```
seq_a, seq_b = [1,4,3,3,2], [4,3,3,2,2]
```

When I use a python implementation (im working in Python 3.11) of the NW algorithm (**sequence_align**), it looks like this and produces the below results:

```
from sequence_align.pairwise import needleman_wunsch

seq_a, seq_b = [1,4,3,3,2], [4,3,3,2,2]

aligned_seq_a, aligned_seq_b = needleman_wunsch(
    seq_a,
    seq_b,
    match_score=1.0,
    mismatch_score=-1.0,
    indel_score=-1.0,
    gap="_",
)

print(aligned_seq_a)
print(aligned_seq_b)
```

The results are

```
[1, 4, 3, 3, '_', 2]
['_', 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

However, I want my result to be

```
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, '_']
['_', 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

The difference is, that I want it to be more important for the algorithm to maintain a "continuous" sequence, than to care about a raster shift.

NW prioritized the provided solution, because the 2nd "2" of the seq_b has the same index than the "2" at the end of seq_a. However, for my use case I would prefer continuity, given that from the second index on, the whole sequence is already shifted, so no penalty shall be given anymore for shifts.

Do you have any idea if to achieve this by manipulating the three parameters (match_score, missmatch_score, and indel_score (i.e., gap)) ?

Could other packages or other algorithms provide the intended solution?

Thank you very much for any help.